# Comparing two string values with an if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using `excel 2010` and want to give out `1` if it's true and `0` if it's false for a given string.

I tried:

```
=IF((EXACT(G2;"V") OR EXACT(G2;"K"));"1";"0")
```

However, this always gives me an error.What's wrong with this formula?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you use the `OR` formula. Try this:

```
=IF(OR(EXACT(G2;"V");EXACT(G2;"K"));"1";"0")
```

It is indeed:

```
OR(Test; Test; Test; ...)
```

Note:

1. I'm not sure why you used `"1"` and `"0"`, but you can drop the quotes if you don't mind having numbers.
2. You might also simply use:

   ```
   =OR(EXACT(G2;"V");EXACT(G2;"K"))
   ```

To get the result as `TRUE` or `FALSE`, or if you want to get `1` or `0`...

```
=OR(EXACT(G2;"V");EXACT(G2;"K"))*1
```

Comment: @pnuts I didn't check the `1` and `0`, but I updated my answer for that now. `EXACT` is case insensitive, which I guess is what the OP might be looking for, because `="v"="V"` is true in excel, but `=EXACT("V"; "v")` is false.

Comment: @pnuts Maybe... if `v` and `V` were indeed meant to be different, then we'd be making false assumptions!

Comment: This syntax will also work `=OR(EXACT(G2;{"V";"K"})`